# Why I cannot print array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int a[] = new int [80];
       int j = 1;
       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i=+2){
          a[i] = j;
          a[i+1] = j;
          j++;
       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

The program did not print out anything when I run it, I want to know why and how can I fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Because your loop never ends. You have written `i=+2` instead of `i+=2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i=+2` and `i+=2` are not the same thing.  The former means to set it to 2.  The latter means to increment it by two.

Comment: Shouldn't you be experienced enough to know that typo question should be closed?

Comment: I've still flagged it as such, calm down.

Comment: You and also want to farm reputation for off-topic questions?

Comment: Given that I know that this reputation gets removed if/when the question gets closed, I'm going to go with "no".

Comment: It really gets removed? Interesting.

Comment: @Gendarme Luckily

Comment: *"I'm going to go with "no""* You know that questions that have positive scored answers are less likely to get deleted.